# MIME type Error in Sinatra Starting Application

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm currently building a simple Interactive Calendar Sinatra application, and I keep getting an error that claims the MIME type is not a supported style-type.

I am trying to link a stylesheet referenced in the :home erb view. The view is in a directory titled stylesheets in the home directory.

File Paths:

Root > Stylesheets > style.css
Root > views > home.erb

[Link Tag for Stylesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60ABy.png)

[Image of the MIME Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmWWK.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Any files you want Sinatra to serve need to be in the `public` directory. Move your stylesheet so it is at `public/stylesheets/style.css`.

What is happening at the moment is the browser is making the request but Sinatra cannot find the file (as it is in the wrong place) and is returning a HTML page with the 404 error. Chrome then sees the content type isn’t a stylesheet, and so issues the error you see.

Comment: Ok, was able to fix it by adding a public directory. Thanks